# Why zsh behaves as less when querying a (postgresql) database?

Tags: zsh, less, postgresql

### Context

- `zsh` shell,
- `oh-my-zsh` framework,
- no special `zsh`'s configuration about `postgresql`.

### Trouble

I noticed an annoying behavior: when querying the database, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable ;
```

it behaves as `less` (with `(END)`) and going back needs to "close" the `less` (with `q` shortcut) which means I cannot read the result of a previous query when typing the next one.

On the contrary, `bash` hasn't this behavior: after a query, the result is displayed and it is possible to type the next query.

### Question

How can I customize `zsh` in order it behaves as `bash` in this respect?

Comment: What's stranger is why you don't get that behaviour with `bash` since it's the default behaviour of `psql`. Do you have `export PAGER=cat` in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`? Or maybe `export LESS=FX` to tell `less` to not use the alternate screen and quit if the text fits on one screen?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Nothing about `PAGER` (nor `pager`) in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`. I don't know how to check whether `LESS` has been exported to `FX`.

Comment: Compare `echo "PAGER: $PAGER LESS: $LESS"` in `bash` and `zsh`.

Comment: (note that it could also have been done in `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash_profile` or the equivalent for `bashrc` on your system). In any case neither `zsh` nor `bash` set those variables by themselves, it would have been done by configuration (by you or by your software distribution)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The result of `echo "PAGER: $PAGER LESS: $LESS"` is, (a) in `bash`: `PAGER:  LESS:`, (b) in `zsh`: `PAGER: less LESS: -R`. There is nothing related to `PAGER` in `/etc/profile` and my Linux distro (Mageia 5) doesn't provide any `/etc/bash_profile` file.

Comment: Then it's hard to tell what may cause the behaviour of psql to change when invoked from `bash`. Possibly `.bashrc` sets a `PSQLRC` variable? Or `HOME` is set differently?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas In `~/.bashrc`, nothing about `PSQLRC`  and nothing about `HOME`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that your shell is setting the `PAGER` environment variable.

Try unsetting it before running psql:

```
user@host% unset PAGER
```

You can also try setting the pager pset value to "off" like this from the postgresql shell:

```
user=> \pset pager off
```

This will toggle use of the pager on or off.  You can also set it to use a specific pager (like `more`, `less`, `cat`, etc.).

More info from the psql man page:

```
pager

    Controls use of a pager for query and psql help output. If the
environment variable PAGER is set, the output is piped to the
specified program. Otherwise a platform-dependent default (such as
more) is used.

    When the pager is off, the pager is not used. When the pager is on,
the pager is used only when appropriate, i.e. the output is to a
terminal and will not fit on the screen. (psql does not do a perfect
job of estimating when to use the pager.) \pset pager turns the pager
on and off. Pager can also be set to always, which causes the pager to
be always used.
```

Comment: If I'm right, toggling the pager off from the `postgresql` shell needs `\pset pager off` (and without any `;`).

Comment: I believe that would actually set the pager to a command called `off`, not actually turn it off.

Comment: You may be right. I haven't actually tried it.

Comment: Just tried. You're right. `\pset pager off` works. Editing.

Answer (score 5):

You could shut it off altogether by commenting

```
cat ~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/misc.zsh
...
#env_default 'PAGER' 'less'                                                        
#env_default 'LESS' '-R'                                                           
...
```

Then open a new terminal and try again; or..

```
exec zsh (in the same terminal)
```